# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while doing api post request in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, forms, fetch, fetch-api, react-hook-form

I am trying to send form data and do a post request on API and get predictions but I am getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` while doing. I have checked the API and it is perfectly fine. I have attached the post request below. I was guessing there is a problem with forms. please correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

```js
const FirstProject = () => {
  const [solutestate, setSoluteState] = useState("");
  const [solventstate, setSolventState] = useState("");
  const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState("");
  const [Error, setError] = useState(null);

  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      solute: "",
      solvent: "",
    },
  });

  const formData = new FormData();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    formData.set("solute", data.solute);
    formData.set("solvent", data.solvent);

    fetch("https://flask-api-test1.herokuapp.com/predict", {
      method: "post",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setFetchData(result.result.predictions);
        //console.log(result.result.predictions);
        //console.log(Object.entries(result));
        // setIsPending(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(data);
        setError(err.error);
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
 <input
  {...register("solute")}
  placeholder="First Name"
  onChange={(e) => setSoluteState(e.target.value)}
  value={solutestate}
 />
 <input
  {...register("solvent")}
  placeholder="First Name"
  onChange={(e) => setSolventState(e.target.value)}
  value={solventstate}
 />
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you show me the request logs from network pane

Comment: @abhipatil I have attached the image please take a look

Answer (score 0):

The `json()` method of the `Response` interface takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise which resolves with the result of parsing the body text as `JSON`, but your request for `API` return `500` status code. You can handle it like this:

```
.then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
       return res.json();
    }
    throw "Something went wrong";
 })
```

instead of

```
.then((res) => res.json())
```

Comment: I am getting "something went wrong" when I ran your code

Comment: Of course,  it work this code  `throw "Something went wrong";
 })`,  Server API is broken and  your request return `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: @harsh your server is crashing when you hit the api. you should debug whats wrong with your server.